# I need help pointing out the mistake in this code that is meant to import a text file and store the data in differenet variables

Tags: c

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_APPOINTMENTS 50

int main(){

     int appointmentCount = importAppointments("appointmentData.txt", appoints, MAX_APPOINTMENTS);
     printf("Imported %d appointment records...\n\n", appointmentCount);

     return 0;

}

int importAppointments(char *filename, struct Appointment appoints[], int max){
    
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    if (file != NULL)
    {

        while (i < max && fscanf(file, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d%c",
              &appoints[i].patientNumber, &appoints[i].date.year, &appoints[i].date.month,
              &appoints[i].date.day, &appoints[i].time.hour, &appoints[i].time.min, &ch) == 7)
        {

            if(ch != '\n')
            {
                while(fgetc(file) != '\n');
            }
        
            i++;
        }
        
        
        fclose(file);
        file = NULL;
    }else{

        printf("Error opening file: %s\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    return i;
}
```

i am trying to read this text:

```
1040,2024,2,29,13,0
1112,2027,3,12,13,0
1048,2026,6,20,10,30
1080,2024,2,29,10,30
1104,2026,6,9,14,0
1088,2024,2,29,11,30
1104,2024,2,29,14,0
1112,2024,2,29,12,0
1056,2025,2,28,11,30
1024,2024,2,29,10,0
1032,2024,2,29,13,30
1120,2024,2,29,11,0
1112,2027,3,10,11,0
1128,2024,2,29,12,30
1024,2027,3,12,10,30
```

I keep getting an error; the code is not able to read file; I've gone through some of the troubleshooting steps but wasn't able to find the problem.
I checked if the files are in the same directory, checked if there is a typo, etc.

Comment: Not able to open the file meaning `printf("Error opening file: %s\n", filename);` is executed or something else? How are you running the program? Where is the file in relation to it? Have you tried an absolute path? This code doesn't compile for several reasons. https://godbolt.org/z/TzY4K6f3j If the problem is with the operation of the program and not just not opening the file you should edit the question to include the missing pieces.

Comment: You need a prototype for the function or move `main()` to the bottom to get it compile cleanly.  `appoints` is undeclared in `main()`, and you need a definition of `struct Appointment` and `struct` you use for `date`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `main()`: you need a prototype for `importAppointments()` or move `main()` the bottom of the file.
2. `main()`: `appoints` is undeclared.
3. `struct Appointment` is not declared.
4. As for the particular error message, it suggest your file `appointmentData.txt` is not readable in the current working directory.  You could use `getcwd()` to find out what that is.  Also make sure you look at the owner/group/permission of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Appointment {
    int patientNumber;
    struct {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
    } date;
    struct {
        int hour;
        int min;
    } time;
};

#define MAX_APPOINTMENTS 50

int importAppointments(char *filename, struct Appointment appoints[], int max){
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!file) {
        printf("Error opening file: %s\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    while (i < max && fscanf(file, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d%c",
            &appoints[i].patientNumber, &appoints[i].date.year, &appoints[i].date.month,
            &appoints[i].date.day, &appoints[i].time.hour, &appoints[i].time.min, &ch) == 7) {
        if(ch != '\n')
            while(fgetc(file) != '\n');
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return i;
}

void printAppointments(size_t n, struct Appointment appoints[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("patient number: %d\n"
            "date (YYYY/MM/DD): %d/%d/%d\n"
            "time: %d:%d\n"
            "%s",
            appoints[i].patientNumber,
            appoints[i].date.year,
            appoints[i].date.month,
            appoints[i].date.day,
            appoints[i].time.hour,
            appoints[i].time.min,
            i + 1 < n ? "-\n" : ""
        );

}


int main(void) {
    struct Appointment appoints[MAX_APPOINTMENTS];
    int appointmentCount = importAppointments("appointmentData.txt", appoints, MAX_APPOINTMENTS);
    printf("Imported %d appointment records...\n\n", appointmentCount);
    printAppointments(appointmentCount, appoints);
}
```

and example output:

```
Imported 15 appointment records...

patient number: 1040
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 13:0
-
patient number: 1112
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2027/3/12
time: 13:0
-
patient number: 1048
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2026/6/20
time: 10:30
-
patient number: 1080
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 10:30
-
patient number: 1104
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2026/6/9
time: 14:0
-
patient number: 1088
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 11:30
-
patient number: 1104
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 14:0
-
patient number: 1112
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 12:0
-
patient number: 1056
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2025/2/28
time: 11:30
-
patient number: 1024
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 10:0
-
patient number: 1032
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 13:30
-
patient number: 1120
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 11:0
-
patient number: 1112
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2027/3/10
time: 11:0
-
patient number: 1128
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2024/2/29
time: 12:30
-
patient number: 1024
date (YYYY/MM/DD): 2027/3/12
time: 10:30
```